# Authorization token not present in header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin, authorize-attribute

So, I have a custom authentication token that I use to secure my web.api project. Now this is a bearer type token which I pass along with the header and I have managed to seamlessly consume it within my WebAPI project.

The complexity is that I am not being able to use it with my MVC project. The `[Authorize]` tag on MVC uses a `System.Web.Mvc` library instead of `System.Web.Http`. To check what is happening to my header which contains the authorization token, I used a custom Token attribute.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
```

In my above function, when I peek into the header using `context.HttpContext.Request.Headers`, I see that there is not Authorization token in the header. This is absurd as I use angular injectors to add the `Bearer` token and it is very much present in the client request being sent out.

What am I not doing to receive this token?

**[Update]**

So after a bit of debugging I just noticed that the Authorize attribute is not appended to the redirect URL's. I suppose this is because the application doesn't have angular interceptors working for these calls. Any idea how to append Authorize Bearer token too all requests?

Comment: Why can't you use the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) from `System.Web.Http`?

Comment: The Attribute can be applied only for `ApiController` not `Controller`. It is automatically rejected.

Comment: `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` and `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` both exist though. Use the appropriate one.

Comment: @DavidG I just updated the issue. It's not that these tags are not working, apparently my Authorization Bearer tokens are not getting added! =/

Comment: Wouldn't the Authorize header be located in the `context.HttpContext.Request.Headers` instead of the response headers? I'm a little confused about your implementation, especially when you mention redirecting URLs.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, yep that's what I put. I was using intellisense so I type out the wrong path. I used `Request`, was not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you cannot inject values into the header when there is a `window.location.href` as the javascript is not executed. It's a direct post by the client browser. The solution is to create a cookie and consume it on the request.